# Subclassing UIView, UIViewController and show the defaults visually in the storyboard and Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

Is there a way to setup subclasses of UIView and UIViewController in Swift to that all new UIView created with Xcode interface builder are using the default values from my subclasses.

In other words, if I create this code for a subclass of UIView :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class GenericUIView: UIView {
    // MARK: Initialization

    @IBInspectable
    var myBackgroundColor : UIColor = UIColor.orange

    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = (myBackgroundColor as! CGColor)
    }

}
```

What do I need to do so that I can see immediately the changes in the Interface Builder of Xcode?

I want to be able to theme my app without having to edit all the properties by hand and still see them visually without building the solution. I know it is sort of possible with overriding drawRect() but that could potentially slow down my app performance when it might be just setting up background and text colour.

Please provide a solution in Swift language if possible.

Patrick

Comment: `UIView` already has a `backgroundColor` property that's inspectable in Interface Builder; why are you trying to add a wrapper property for one that already exists?

Comment: I'm trying to make them default to all my new UIView & UIViewControllers I will create. I don't want to go through all of my views to edit and change the colours all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?   You would have to change all of your views to use this class instead of UIView though.   You'd add other properties like backgroundcolor in the same way (as you seem to know).

```
//
//  DesignableView.swift
//
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class DesignableView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try your solution. The only problem is even though I set values in the code for default settings, it does not show my defaults. I have to go manually to each UIView and adjust the settings manually in the Interface Builder. See the bellow code.

Comment: I tried to paste code here but it does not look proper without formatting. I created and answer with the code.

Comment: I had hoped that once IB reloaded the objects, it'd take the defaults for you.

Comment: I'll play around with it later.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have it. Can anyone confirm if this is Best Practice and if this would cause other issue in my program later? It's actually quite simpler then I thought :
    import UIKit

```
@IBDesignable
class GView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor

    }
}
```